# Search and Return key ranging in an array - using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows

```
[1428997804] => False
[1428997830] => False
[1428997921] => False
[1428997947] => True
[1428998025] => False
[1428998051] => False
[1428998077] => False
[1428998116] => False
[1428998142] => False
[1428998272] => False
[1428998389] => False
[1428998415] => False
[1428998467] => False
[1428998493] => False
[1428998519] => False
[1428998532] => False
[1428998623] => False
[1428998649] => False
[1428998675] => False
```

and UI(Front End form) have a "start from" as text field, "end to" as text fields with a submit button. User enter the value from the above array in "start from" as 1428998116 and "end to" as 1428998467. Now I need to return an array which fall in between those ranges with the Values (True/False) corresponding to it.

I expect the output as follows:

```
[1428998116] => False
[1428998142] => False
[1428998272] => False
[1428998389] => False
[1428998415] => False
[1428998467] => False
```

I don't have any idea how to implement it. I thought of doing it by array_search but seems not on a correct page.

Can anyone guide me in finishing it.

Comment: I didnt try anything @mrid, I'm not getting any idea in doing it. I wanna to do it by array_search, but not sure whether I'm page or not. So asking me to guide.

Comment: Are keys all numeric; i.e., sorted?

Comment: yes @BusyBeaver

Comment: A simple loop over your array, compare the key for whether it is >= and <= the two values entered by the user - if yes, put it in a new array, if not, next ... Of course you can get a little fancier than that and use f.e. array_filter instead of a loop, if you like.

Comment: In your example the user picked two values that exists as keys. Is this a valid suggestion or is it possible for the user to pick values that has no key in the array?

Comment: "Can anyone guide me in finishing it.". It looks like actually we need to guide you in starting it? This site is used by volunteers. We will gladly make an effort to help you if you can show you made some effort yourself. if you don't know what to do at all, you can research it. Arrays are a fairly basic concept in PHP (and programming in general). There is _a lot_ of material out there about how to manipulate them. Then you need to work out the logic (rules) you need to get your output - this is a logic task not a programming one, and then translate that to code.

Comment: If you try that and get stuck with any part of it, then you can post the code here and explain the problem, and people will happily help to fix it. They won't, in general, just spoon-feed you the answer when you don't seem to have even made an attempt to discover the basics. Nobody learns anything by doing that.

Comment: @KiranKumar please have you look on working demo in my answer .Also at least try to implement some thing first which may lead you to better solution  :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a loop, starting from `$start_from` and going to `$end_to`, that builds a new array.

Read more about [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php), [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

```
<?php
$array = array(10 => 1,
               20 => 2,
               30 => 3,
               40 => 4,
               50 => 5,
               60 => 6,
               70 => 7,
               80 => 8,
               90 => 9);
// start and end keys of the sub-array you want to extract
$start_from = 20;
$end_to = 50;
// Advance the internal pointer of the array
// until you rach the $start_from key
while (key($array) !== $start_from) {
    next($array);
}

// Now build the sub array
$slice = array();
while (key($array) <= $end_to) {
    $slice[key($array)] = current($array);
    next($array);
}

// Reset the internal array pointer
// just in case you need to loop again
// in the future
reset($array);

?>
```

At the end `$slice` would be:

```
Array
(
    [20] => 2
    [30] => 3
    [40] => 4
    [50] => 5
)
```

Comment: @JoshuaK You are right, I'll fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

**Check working demo here**: https://eval.in/866420

```
$array = [];
$array[1428997804] = False;
$array[1428997830] = False;
$array[1428997921] = False;
$array[1428997947] = True;
$array[1428998025] = False;
$array[1428998051] = False;
$array[1428998077] = False;
$array[1428998116] = False;
$array[1428998142] = False;
$array[1428998272] = False;
$array[1428998389] = False;
$array[1428998415] = False;
$array[1428998467] = False;
$array[1428998493] = False;
$array[1428998519] = False;
$array[1428998532] = False;
$array[1428998623] = False;
$array[1428998649] = False;
$array[1428998675] = False;
$startFrom = 1428998116;
$endTo = 1428998467;

$slice = array_filter($array, function($k) use ($startFrom, $endTo) {
    return ($k >= $startFrom && $k <= $endTo) ? true : false ;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($slice);
```

Answer (score 0):

if start and end has corresponding keys inside the array it's quite easy:

```
function findPos($keyNeedle, $array) {
    // array_search returns the key of the element given by the first Argument. Because of calling findPos with $keys as second argument it returns the index of the key we're looking for.
    return array_search($keyNeedle, $array);
}
// create an Array with all the keys and numbered index
$keys = array_keys($array);
// $start is the index of the given key inside of the keys array
$start = findPos(1428998116, $keys);
// $end is the index of the given key inside of the keys array
$end = findPos(1428998467, $keys);
var_dump(
    array_slice($array, $start, $end-$start+1, true); // true = preserve keys!
);
```

EDIT: **removed array_combine and one array_slice because there is no need for it when using the fourth parameter of array_slice**

Comment: Why two functions `findStart()` and `findEnd()` instead of just one (say `find_it()`)?

Comment: @BusyBeaver I wasn't sure if there is a key for every value that a user can pick. If not the functions are used to search for the next (start) or prev (end) key. So I used two functions. So the questioneer can implement a binary search inside this functions for the sorted array. I thought of this while writing the answer, but you're right: In the final version of this answer it doesn't matter. I change it for clarification.

Comment: Still looks not really performant to me. 6 expensive function calls will waste a lot of time when it comes to big arrays :)

Comment: @BusyBeaver executed both solutions (mine and yours) and they very similar. mine is a bit faster: Mine: 0.0501618385314942, Yours: 0.059713125228882 (both with 10000 loops)

Comment: I was speaking about big data... `2**20` and above

Comment: @BusyBeaver Dataset of `2**15`: Mine: 114.15084314346 Yours: 155.44421195984. It's not getting better. EDIT: But it's just looping and use of microtime. No use of a benchmark class. Feel free to make your own tests and let me know :)

Comment: Mmh, it may depends on other factors... Anyway it wasn't specified by OP so it's fine ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155093/discussion-between-joshua-k-and-busy-beaver).

Comment: benchmark of the new version of the code: 58.259648084641 (10000 loops and 2**15 records)